# Java regex not functioning as expected illegal character exception

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regex that I built, which works in regex101.com:

`(\(.+?\))/g`

The regex identifies groups of paren contained text. For example, in the string:

"test item (paren text here) more random content (inside content)"

It matches: (paren text here), and (inside content).

While this combination works in regex101 and even in Javascript, when I have been attempting to use it in Java, I consistently get the error that I am using an illegal escape character. For example, I get that error with the below:

```
String searchString = "asfdasdf asdfasd asdfasd (adfasdf) asdfasd 
asdfasd AND asdfasdfasd (asfdasd) asfdasdfas";
 
        String pattern = "/(\(.+?\))/g";
        
        Pattern patternFound = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = patternFound.matcher(searchString);
        
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

When I use:

`String pattern = "/(\\(.+?\\))/g";`

I no longer receive the error, but the regex no longer works and returns false.

How can I properly format my regex so that it works in Java the same as it does on regex101 and in JavaScript?

Comment: It might make sense to include the exact escaped version you've tried, since escaping is mandatory.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, you can use https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quickrex for a more Java centric Regexp.

Comment: It should be: `String pattern = "(\\(.+?\\))";` as there are no regex delimiters in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that Java don't use the // delimiter: you muse use `"(\\(.+?\\))"`.

The syntax differs from JavaScript because there is actually a sugar syntax for pattern: `/azerty/g` is same as `new RegEx("azerty", "g")`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#syntax

In Java, we only have `Pattern.compile` and flags are represented by ints.